# Cannot download files with Greek names

Tags: python, python-3.x

Every time i try to download a file with using:

```
return static_file( filename, root=filepath, download=True )
```

Python errors saying:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 14-33: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Myy system is se to `LANG=el_GR.utf-8` though.

How will i be able to download correctly files with Greek names?

Comment: try using a function like fileEncoding = "el_GR.utf-8"

Comment: or omit the download argument completely

Comment: You mean like this? `return tatic_file( filename.encode("utf-8"), root=filepath, download=True )` ? If you mean that then i do have tried it but it return an error.

Comment: The `return` statement is irrelevant; what's `static_file`?

Comment: How you mean? 'Its the function being used to send a file to the users browser. but i want to print a string first ebfore sending the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encoding the filename separately before using it? I often find that when I try to add ".encode("utf-8")" in a function, I too get an error, however, when I encode in a variable first it works.

```
filename = filename.encode("utf-8")
return pdata, static_file( filename, root=filepath, download=True )
```

Otherwise, you can also try adding this to the top of your code:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

Also have a look at this link [Unicode Types](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type)
It shows Unicode usage in python.

Comment: I do have the latter in top and i also trried encoding the variable first but iam getting the error `TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'",)`

Comment: Could you send the name of one of the files? so we can see where the errors come from?

Comment: I have checked by printing the filenames and they are all correct and they do exists as `os.path.exist` is shown. Latin names appear correctly while for e.g. a greek filanem appears in the browser when i try to print it as `ÎÎ¹Î¿Î³ÏÎ±ÏÎ¹ÎºÏ - ÎÎ¯ÎºÎ¿Ï.docx`

Comment: Try this site [Python Standard Encoding](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html)

It has a list of different encoding languages, see if any of these give you the desired output when encoding.

What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python v3.6.1 Can you show me how to write it in code?

Comment: you'll want to exchange "utf-8" with one of the values from the table
eg:
`filename = filename.encode("cp737")`

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i decided to use a middleware, that being 'download.html' template:

```
return template( 'download.html', authuser=authuser, filename=filename )
```

and serve the file with 'meta-equiv' as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="5;URL=http://superhost.gr/static/files/{{ filename }}">
```

It seems though that the Greek filename isn't pass from the wsgi app to html template properly becasue i receiving this error when iam referencing the `filename' variable.

```
The requested URL /static/files/ÃŽÂ’ÃŽÂ¹ÃŽÂ¿ÃŽÂ³ÃÂÃŽÂ±ÃÂ†ÃŽÂ¹ÃŽÂºÃÂŒ - ÃŽÂÃŽÂ¯ÃŽÂºÃŽÂ¿ÃÂ‚.docx was not found on this server.
```

Why is that?

Comment: I found the solution to this! Actually what needed to be done is placing an html attribute in the html form data so to properly post the values as "utf-8" `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="%s">` The above did the trick. I was under the impression that html post data supposed to be utf-8 by  default though.